# Has any elected American Politician endorsed proportional representation?

Tags: united-states, voting-systems

Has any elected American [politician](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1502/23), on the state or federal level, endorsed using proportional representation to elect American legislators? I would consider an endorsement of single transferable vote, party-list ballots, mixed-member proportional representation, or any other proportional representation system, or unspecified support for proportional representation an endorsement.

One imagines that, seeing as how almost every elected American politician is a member of a major party, they would not want to risk their jobs by promoting a system that could promote alternate parties, but nevertheless, has any american politician endorsed proportional representation? Bonus points if they have endorsed it while holding office or while running for office as part of a major party.

Comment: Ron Paul? (I'm just guessing but it's an informed guess). Kucinich? Generally look for minor 3rd party people, there's plenty of those on state level.

Comment: Avi, This is a great question - AND i know somebody out there is going to say "define politician." You did a great job starting that discussion - and I moved the fuller discussion to meta, just in case.

Comment: For my purposes, somebody who holds elected office. For the purposes of this question, I have a preference towards a legislator from a major party.

Comment: I disagree with Affable Geek.  I don't like this question, and here's why.  When I judge a question, what I mostly do is imagine a basic user story where a third party is curious about something, finds this question, sees what would theoretically be a good answer to this question, and leaves with his or her curiosity satisfied.  I can't imagine this question fitting into that user story.

Comment: @SamIam you don't think a person, curious about the feasibility of the implementation of PR in the US, might wonder if a politician endorsed it.

Comment: @Avi I am going to fabricate an answer for you.  Tell me if this is an answer that satisfies your curiosity.  `Yes, at least one politician has:  It was Bob Dole <insert evidence here>`  If you received an answer like that, would you consider your the matter settled? Or would be curious as to whether there was exactly 1 politician or multiple?

Comment: @Avi How about this answer:  `No, No politician has ever supported it.  <insert the enumerated list of opportunities that a politician might have to show support for it in public here.  If a politician has explicitly come out against it, you can skip this for that politician, It's less than 100 pages, so it's far far far from exhaustive.>`  Would you consider the matter settled then?  or would you consider the possibility that I might have missed one

Comment: @SamIAm your first answer would satisfy (and surprise) me. If you've gone through a comprehensive or at least substantial search for any politician who has endorsed it and turned up nothing, that would also satisfy me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, at least 1 politician has supported proportional representation:  Dennis Kucinich

> Kucinich replied: Well, it should happen. So, it’s really a step towards democratization, so that points of view that are held in the general populace are not squelched because they don’t reach some numerical sigificance that we call a majority. You know, majority politics are all very interesting, but what’s happening in the United States, with increasingly blurring the differences between the two parties, there’s a hunger for alternatives, and there’s a hunger for those alternatives to find a means of inclusion into the process. So, certainly, that’s one way to do it. And we need to broaden our discussion in America. When you come here (to Sweden) and you see so many different political persuasions represented, and our politics back home are monochromatic – I mean, increasingly. It’s grey, and you can’t really tell the difference. Here, you can. But at the same time, there’s a common commitment to the nation. **We need to awaken those sentiments in America. And one way to do it is proportional representation**.”

http://www.ballot-access.org/2014/07/dennis-kucinich-says-he-favors-proportional-representation/

Comment: Member of a major party, ran for and held office. This is a good answer.

Comment: @Avi - heh. I'll give myself a pat on the back for proposing that candidate for an answer without even doing research :)